# Is the sentence, I slept at 11, wrong?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

I saw a post somewhere stating that using **at** with **sleep** is wrong. It said something about **verb aspect**.

Is it really wrong? Why? What's the correct sentence to convey the same message?

Comment: @Rathony The post said opposite of what you do. 11 is a point of time, so at is fine while sleep is an activity which takes a period of time and hence the usage feels unnatural.

Comment: Of course, I went to bed (sleep) at 11 would be more idiomatic.

Comment: What message are you trying to convey? I went to sleep at 11, I fell asleep at 11, I used to go to sleep at 11, I was asleep at 11.... In American English *I slept at 11* is unnatural.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I went to sleep at 11 is what I want to say.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Why is I slept at 11 unnatural?

Comment: *"I slept at 11 pm"* is unnatural because *"sleep"* is something we do for an extended period of time. For a more extreme example, saying *"I grew at 11 pm"* is unnatural, although *"I grew two inches last year"* is fine. (And if you're growing all year, presumably you're doing it at 11 pm as well.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [to "sleep" vs to "go to sleep"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59124/to-sleep-vs-to-go-to-sleep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, one could use *I slept at 11*, but it is not the most natural or common expression available. One time I might use it  would be when reporting past events or conditions, and then I'd put the times first:

*At 6, I awoke.*
*At noon I played football.*
 *At 5 I partied.*
*At 11 I slept.*

But note *at 11 I slept* does not mean *I went to sleep at 11*. It means *at 11 I was asleep*. This is the past simple  equivalent to the past progressive  *At 11 I was sleeping* (or *I was sleeping at 11*)  which is more common to say, because *to sleep* is an action that occurs over time. We don't normally  use it in contemporary English to mean, for instance, *I started to sleep*.

In everyday (American) English, I wouldn't use *I slept at 11* but one of the following alternatives, depending on what I wanted to express:

I went to sleep at 11
I fell asleep at 11
I was asleep at 11
I was sleeping at 11
I used to go to sleep at 11
Etc.

Comment: The natural verb form to use is past continuous: *"I was sleeping at 11"*.

Comment: @Peter if by normal, you mean   much more common. Cf *I bowled at 11* v *I was bowling at 11*.